# .htaccess rewrite for WordPress tag archive, redirect to search

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, tags

WordPress WooCommerce shop tag archives, love em or hate em!

I'd like to redirect a visit to:

`http://example.com/shop-tag/this-silly-tag/`
to `http://example.com/?s=this+silly+tag`

`?s=` does the search magic with my current theme.

I think this is more useful for my visitors, finding their way via some Google linked tag archive.

I've attempted it with no success. Any `.htaccess` experts out there with a moment to help me?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^shop-tag/([^&]+)
RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop-tag/(.*) http://example.com/?s=%1? [R=302,L]
```

Is what I've tried. An ill-educated guess.

Comment: A RewriteCond only influences the following RewriteRule, not a RedirectMatch directive. The RewriteCond is pretty pointless to begin with - your incoming URL does not contain `shop-tag` in the query string. And I am assuming your example going from `this-silly-tag` to `?s=silly-tag` was just an oversight, it is `silly-tag` to `?s=silly-tag`, yes?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^tag/(.*) /?s=%1? [R=302,L]` should do the job.

Comment: @CBroe: Probably you meant `RewriteRule ^tag/(.*) /?s=$1? [R=302,L]` though I see no point of using this rule as it exposes internal URL to visitors.

Comment: @CBroe you are quite right, my real world setup is woocommerce so what follows 'shop-tag' is what I'm attempting to re-direct. Let me try these solutions! Wordpress created many of its own Rewrite rules in my htaccess, hopefully this will play nice. Thanks for your input.

Comment: That got me in the 'ball park'. Thank you. Not quite there, but here's what works: 

`RewriteRule ^shop-tag/(.*)/$ /?s=$1 [R=302,L]`

I'd like to also search and replace the string that follows the initial query 'this-silly-tag' and replace the hyphens with plus signs + for the search to function.